# How can i solve SwiftOCR importing problem?

Tags: swift5, xcode11

i'm nicely finished pod installing but my project (import SwiftOCR) isn't working.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Jy92.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I thinks it does not work with swift 5 & Xcode 11 because pod's swift version is 3.0 so there can be a compatibility issue. However, if you want to do the same without using any library and using Core ML, here is a link to my solution check this [link](https://github.com/umerFarooki/CoreMLTextScanner.git)